# VB6 app printing Crystal Report to Adobe Distiller PDF - how to set PDF filename?

Tags: pdf, vb6, crystal-reports, acrobat

I've got a legacy app that I'm maintaining.  It's a VB6 app that calls a Crystal Report (Crystal 8 it looks like) and then prints programmatically to the default printer, which is set up as Acrobat Distiller (v5.0).  When it prints to PDF, it's automatically placing the resulting PDF in a folder (c:\pdf) and naming it as the first 5 characters of the crystal report *filename*. What's happening is that two reports with the same characters at the front of the *filename* are getting printed one after another, and the second is overwriting the first.

1. Are there settings somewhere for how distiller produces output?  Can I adjust the output path, or the *filename*?  Where/why is it only using the first five characters of the report *filename* as output?  Or is that a Crystal function?
2. Is there a way to define the output PDF *filename* when printing from Crystal?  It is printing the report like so:

```
With CrPt
        .Connect = "DSN=" & Trim(sServerName) & ";UID=usernam;PWD=password;DSQ=database"
        .ReportFileName = sReport
        .Formulas(0) = "version=""" & App.Major & "." & App.Minor & "." & App.Revision & """"
        .Destination = crptToPrinter
        .Action = 1
    End With
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I like your description, by the way.  Detailed and legible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is just a code snippet and there's more to the entire process. Try searching your entire VB6 code for `Sreport`.  If you can find how `Sreport` is defined, that may answer your question.

I'm guessing somewhere is a line that says something like,

```
Sreport="C:\pdf\" & left(somevar,5)
```

Change that 5 to a 10 and you're good to go.

Comment: CrPt is the Crystal Report object; sReport is the full path filename to the .rpt file.  

I did find where the output folder is set, it seems to be a function of the port on the Adobe Distiller printer device.  I think the naming convention of the PDF is some sort of Distiller default...I think I can set an option to prompt for a filename but that's probably going to break other processes that rely on automation in this mess.

I think I'm ending up recreating the report in SSRS and having the user run that...the combo of VB6/Crystal/Adobe is a colossal mess.

Comment: ah. In that case, my suggestion is wrong since I misinterpreted your question.  If you're looking for an alternative, I'd suggest Visual Cut. With VC, you can export your .rpt to .pdf and print it with just 1 batch command line. It'll take the VB6 & Adobe out of the equation. You can also burst report by group if needed.